# Javascripts fetch delete request method doesn't work when in return dispatch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch, redux-thunk

I have stumbled upon very strange problem in my code.

This fetch delete request action works very well.

```
export const deleteUser = id => {
    fetch(`${BASE_ENDPOINT}/users/${id}`, {
        method: 'DELETE'
    }); 
};
```

But this modified one doesn't?!?

```
export const deleteUser = id => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch(`${BASE_ENDPOINT}/users/${id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE'
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                if (res.error) throw Error(res.error);
                dispatch(deleteUserSuccess(true));
                return res;
            })
            .catch(error => dispatch(deleteUserError(error)));
    };
};
```

It simply doesn't send the request to the server, as it should; which I have verified by inspecting Chrome's developer tools console Network tab. No requests to the server are being made.

Here is my Actions.js

```
import { BASE_ENDPOINT } from '../shared/Constants';

import { 
    FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
    FETCH_USERS_ERROR, 
    DELETE_USER_SUCCESS,
    DELETE_USER_ERROR
} from './Types';

const fetchUsersSuccess = users => ({
    type: FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS,
    users
});

const fetchUsersError = error => ({
    type: FETCH_USERS_ERROR,
    error
});

const deleteUserSuccess = deleted => ({
    type: DELETE_USER_SUCCESS,
    deleted
});

const deleteUserError = error => ({
    type: DELETE_USER_ERROR,
    error
});

export const fetchUsers = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch(`${BASE_ENDPOINT}/users/`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                if (res.error) throw Error(res.error);
                dispatch(fetchUsersSuccess(res));
                return res;
            })
            .catch(error => dispatch(fetchUsersError(error)));
    };
};

export const deleteUser = id => {
    return dispatch => {
        fetch(`${BASE_ENDPOINT}/users/${id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE'
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                if (res.error) throw Error(res.error);
                dispatch(deleteUserSuccess(true));
                return res;
            })
            .catch(error => dispatch(deleteUserError(error)));
    };
};
```

Here is my Reducers.js

```
const initialState = {
    users: [],
    fetchError: false,
    deleted: false,
    deleteError: false,
};

export const usersReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_USERS_SUCCESS':
            return {
                ...state,
                users: action.users
            };
        case 'FETCH_USERS_ERROR':
            return {
                ...state,
                fetchError: action.error
            };
        case 'DELETE_USER_SUCCESS':
                return {
                    ...state,
                    deleted: action.deleted
                };
        case 'DELETE_USER_ERROR':
            return {
                ...state,
                deleteError: action.error
            };
        default: 
            return state;
    };
};
```

Here is my component Users.js

```
       import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { fetchUsers, deleteUser } from '../../redux/Actions';

import User from './User';

class Users extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUsers();
    }

    shouldRender = () => {
        const { users } = this.props;
        if (users.length !== 0) return true;
        return false;
    };

    shouldRerender = () => {
        const { deleted } = this.props;
        if (deleted) {
            this.forceUpdate();
            return true;
        };
        return false;
    };

    render() {
        const { users, fetchError, deleteError } = this.props;

        if (!this.shouldRender() || !this.shouldRerender()) {
            return (
                <div className='container'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-12 mt-5 pt-5'>
                            <p>Loading!</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <div className='container'>
                    <div className='row'>
                        <div className='col-12 mt-5 pt-5'>
                            {fetchError && <p>{fetchError}</p>}
                            {deleteError && <p>{deleteError}</p>}
                            <table className="table table-striped table-dark">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Name</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Email</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Delete</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    {users.map(user => <User key={user.id} user={user} deleteUser={deleteUser} />)}
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        };
    }
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    users: state.users,
    fetchError: state.fetchError,
    deleted: state.deleted,
    deleteError: state.deleteError
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    fetchUsers: () => dispatch(fetchUsers()),
    deleteUser: (id) => dispatch(deleteUser(id))
});

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Users);
```

and here is my App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { usersReducer } from './redux/Reducers';

import App from './App';

import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

const store = createStore(usersReducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <App />
        </Provider>
    </Router>
, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Any thougths would be apriciated. Thanks in advance!

P.S.

I was able to figer out that I am not passing the id argument to the inner function which I was able to confirm by this modified code.

```
export const deleteUser = id => {
    console.log('id1: ', id);
    return (dispatch, id) => {
        console.log('id2: ', id);
        fetch(`${BASE_ENDPOINT}/users/${id}`, {
            method: 'DELETE'
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                if (res.error) throw Error(res.error);
                dispatch(deleteUserSuccess(true));
                return res;
            })
            .catch(error => dispatch(deleteUserError(error)));
    };
};
```

It only console.log's id1!

Comment: first deleteUser is a function that sends a request, second deleteUser is a function that returns a function that sends a request, how would they work the same way?

Comment: Please show more of your react code. I cannot understand how and where you are using the second deleteUser method!

Comment: This looks correct, is this your first redux-thunk in the project? How did you set up the store, and how are you dispatching the action? You should provide code to form a complete picture.